# How can to change a groupBox.Text?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i change a groupBox.Text to the value/text of the select toolstripmenuitem... how do i get to check which one the user has clicked and how do i get the ".text" of the menu item to transfer it to a variable or right to the groupBox.text.

right now i've been going to every item (have been trying with a few only to see if i can do it properly) with the "click" event and setting it manually, but im certain there's a way to do this automatically... i just couldn't find it yet.

i set the 1st one to be the default one...

- ```
   this.meusDadosToolStripMenuItem.Select();
        groupBox1.Text = meusDadosToolStripMenuItem.Text;//definir o nome da groupbox por default
    }

    private void horárioToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Text = horárioToolStripMenuItem.Text; 
    }

    private void vencimentosToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Text = vencimentosToolStripMenuItem.Text;
    }

    private void meusDadosToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Text = meusDadosToolStripMenuItem.Text;
    }*
  ```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). as TLDR: introductions are not necessary - not even wanted. focus on the problem - and provide _much more details_. relevant code, what behavior you're expecting _exactly_, what you have tried and researched so far...

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Comment: ok sorry, just trying to be polite.

Comment: i'm expecting to get the menu selected item name to present to the user as the groupbox.text so the user can check in which page of the app he's in.

Comment: Does the code work?  What do you mean by "set it automatically"?

Comment: The sender argument is the menuitem clicked. Just cast sender to the correct type or at least a control subtype that surfaces the Text property you want to use in the event.

Comment: this code works, but i need to get it in every "click" event for 15+ items, i wanted to do it with something that would "check" which item the user clicked on to be the active tab and present the right .text on the groupbox..

Comment: Instead of an event handler for each menu item, create a basic handler that all of them subscribe to, then cast the sender: `private void GroupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { groupBox1.Text = ((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Text;}`  Something like that.

Comment: couldn't get it to work.. i'm doing something really wrong for sure. uff... frustrated now. thank you anyways... will keep trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is only 1-level menu, you can use `ItemClicked` event like this:

```
private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ClickedItem.Text);
    }
```

You can also iterate through menu items like this:

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem tsi in menuStrip1.Items)
        {
            tsi.Click += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    var currentMenuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem) sender;
                    Console.WriteLine(currentMenuItem.Text);
                };
        }
```

Again, this will work for 1st level only. If you want to go through all levels, then you will need **recursion**. Here you can check example for `menuStrip1`:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem tsi in menuStrip1.Items)
        {
            IterateMenu(tsi);
        }
    }

    private void IterateMenu(ToolStripMenuItem currentMenuItem)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Assigning {currentMenuItem.Text}");
        currentMenuItem.Click += ClickEvent;
        if (currentMenuItem.HasDropDownItems)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem tsi in currentMenuItem.DropDownItems)
            {
                IterateMenu(tsi);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var currentMenuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
        Console.WriteLine(currentMenuItem.Text);
    }
```

To fit your requirements, change `Console.WriteLine(currentMenuItem.Text);` to `groupBox1.Text = currentMenuItem.Text;`.

EDIT:
Here is version that will not change `groupbox.Text` when menu item has sub-items:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem tsi in menuStrip1.Items)
        {
            IterateMenu(tsi);
        }
    }

    private void IterateMenu(ToolStripMenuItem currentMenuItem)
    {
        if (currentMenuItem.HasDropDownItems)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem tsi in currentMenuItem.DropDownItems)
            {
                IterateMenu(tsi);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentMenuItem.Click += ClickEvent;
        }
    }

    private void ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var currentMenuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
        Console.WriteLine(currentMenuItem.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, this time is goes around and gets all the names, now i want to keep only the one that the user clicks and set it as the groupBox1.Text

the menu strip has 4/5 items, each one with at least 3 sub items.. i want to get the selected sub item text to present it as the groupBox1.Text.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. All you need to do is change line `Console.WriteLine(currentMenuItem.Text);` in `ClickEvent` method to `groupBox1.Text = currentMenuItem.Text;`. When user will click on menu item, groupbox text will change to the tool strip menu text, even if it's sub item.

Comment: Got it mate, thank you. now i just need to solve one more thing here. the user need to click the menu item so the subitem list appears right? i want him to be able to do it but the groupBox can't have the item text, only the subitem but i'll try something

Comment: was a mistake i made earlier, it worked for me.. but how do i explain this.

imagine the menu having 5 items, from 1 to 5. and 3 subitems each. i don't want the user to read 1 to 5 as the groupBox1.Text, only 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, etc..

Comment: i think i explained my badly.. i only want it to change with the sub items... i tried chaging the foreach (ToolStripMenuItem tsi in menuStrip1.Items) to foreach (ToolStripMenuItem tsi in menuStrip1.DropDownItems) to see if it would help me getting only the subs, but it is not possible to do it like this.

Comment: GOT IT! THANK YOU. i'm so dumb.. figured it out. had a line copied on 2 places

Comment: Sure, glad to help. Please mark this answer as accepted and click +1.

Comment: Done it. but i have less than 15 rep. Thanks once more.